# increase Thread start performance in java

Tags: java, multithreading, performance

Is there a way to increase the performance of Thread.start method. as i know Thread.start will call the run method of the tread in a separate thread but i have found that it need time more than simple method call in the calling context.

Comment: Reducing the thread stack size might yield some small improvement...

Comment: Make Thread.start irrelevant by either using a thread pool, as suggested by @pamphet etc, or by signaling a dedicated thread that runs a loop round some wait(), eg. P-C queue.

Comment: thank all thread pool has improved the performance 7x

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Starting threads definitely involves overhead. You may want to consider thread pooling.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/pools.html

Answer (score 2):

`Thread.start` is native. It does a lot more than calling `run` - it uses Operating System calls to create a thread stack and lots of other things. Consider using a [`Thread Pool`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/pools.html).

Answer (score 2):

Starting threads, context switching and destroying threads all require precious CPU cycles. So it is best to use **Thread Pooling** which suits your requirement.

There are various options available:

- Cached Thread Pool - caches some threads to improve performance
- Single Thread pool executor - A single thread executor
- Fixed Thread Pool executor - An executor with fixed size

Switching can be reduced by creating n threads based on your hardware configuration and other parameters.

Advantage of executors over `Thread.start()`:

- Re use of existing threads, so threads are not created every time a task is submitted
- Thread management is done by executors

Answer (score 2):

Thread creation always takes time. The traditional approach

```
new Thread(runnableObj).start();
```

creates new *Thread* everytime we call *start()* method.

Use *Executors*, if you don't want to spend extra time in creating threads while your business logic is being run. You can configure and create *Thread Pools* when your application starts.

[Here](http://java.dzone.com/articles/java-concurrency-%E2%80%93-part-7) is a good short tutorial for *Executors*